# create intersection points of paths on edge of mask. Adobe illustrator

Tags: path, mask, adobe-illustrator

The "A" in the following image is a compound path.

The lines are paths with a white stroke.

The A is a clipping mask that is clipping the white strokes.

I want to create anchor points for each path at the edge of the clipping mask.

[image]

This is what I want to Achieve:

[image: creating anchor points on edge of compound path]

I did this three years ago and can't remember how I did it. It's driving me crazy...

Answer (score 0):

It can be done via Erase mode of the  [Shape Builder](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/creating-shapes-shape-builder-tool.html) tool:

- select all objects (the "A" must be a simple object, not a clipping mask)
- select Shape Builder Tool (Shift M) and pressing Alt erase outers and internals unnecessary parts of lines.

Comment: That is very time consuming. Can you think of a method that will do this automatically?